# Is the German 6-year long position of "researcher for habilitation" (called "Habilitationsstelle") a senior or junior position?

Tags: postdocs, tenure-track, germany, assistant-professor, habilitation

I am trying to understand if a 6-year long position of "researcher for habilitation" (called "Habilitationsstelle"), and that is offered in German universities, would be a junior position (just after the PhD) or with some level of seniority (maybe after 4-6 years of postdocs).

Other way around, what could be the average age for people who start the "Habilitationsstelle" in Germany ? Maybe just after the PhD, or after several years of postdocs ?

Also, could the "Habilitationsstelle" be equivalent to an Assistant Professor?

Comment: From experience: several people I know have started their Habilitationsstelle straight after completion of their PhD

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! Given this comment, to me, it looks like a junior position, with a sort of unique 6-year block of postdoc instead of the very common succession of 1 or 2 years long contracts as postdoc.... Therefore, a sort of long postdoc... :-) Therefore, to my understanding, if for example you have already 5-6 years of postdoc experience (plus other work experiences), this "Habilitationsstelle" does not look like a real step forward in your career, but more a continuation of the current status of postdoc...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One is not supposed to be employed on temporary positions at German universities for more than 6 years after the PhD. While there are exceptions to this rule, this indicates that such a position should be available to recent PhDs.

Such a position shouldn't be considered equivalent to a US-style Assistant Professorship, because of the lack of independence. It is a postdoc position.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arno!! ... But I don't understand something... So, if you have already 5 years of postdocs in another country (i.e. not Germany), and you get that position of "Habilitationsstelle" in Germany, it means that you can be employed for only 1 year for that position of "Habilitationsstelle" in Germany (even though it is a 6-year position)??

Comment: @limone Positions outside of Germany doesn't count for the 6 year rule.

Comment: In addition, if in that position you are supposed to get third-party funds to hire some PhDs (and even 1 post-doc), would that position of "Habilitationsstelle" still be considered  as a postdoc job ??

Comment: Ah ok thanks :-)

Comment: @limone Is this a NachwuchsgruppenleiterIn?

Comment: Well, the word "NachwuchsgruppenleiterIn" was not written explicitly in the job ad, but, during the interview, it was clearly stated to get third-party funds to create a small group with up to 4 PhDs and 1 post-doc (at the very least 1 PhD student)...the job ad was in English and the title was "Researcher for Habilitation (Habilitationsstelle)"...and there was also something like this in the job ad: "It is a qualification position for a total of six years, with a possibility to do a habilitation (qualification as university lecturer)."

Comment: @limone If the role indeed includes applying for funding in your own name, and then being the official supervisor of PhD students, I'd indeed be inclined to consider it an Assistant-Professor-equivalent. On the other hand, it might be that the role is to "assist" the Professor in charge in doing those things.

Comment: Many thanks @Arno!

Comment: Hi, I got something more specific, that I am not able to interpret..."For the first three years, the designation "scientific employee" is applicable. Employment is in accordance with the collective bargaining agreement of the federal states (TV-L). According to this, a temporary appointment with the designation "Akademischer Rat auf Zeit" would theoretically be possible"...

Comment: "Such a position shouldn't be considered equivalent to a US-style Assistant Professorship, because of the lack of independence" I would assume that depends on the specifics of the position, and is something that has to be clarified (and potentially negotiated) with the associated chair. If one gets to publish and apply for funding independently, then it is comparable to a US-style assistant professorship.

Answer (score 4):

In Germany (and countries with similar systems) the route to becoming a professor requires* an additional qualification above your doctorate. This process is known as [Habilitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habilitation). So a "Habilitationsstelle" is the position / job that you will do while working towards this even higher qualification. Same as a Doktorstelle is the position / job you will hold while working towards your doctorate. So yes it is postdoctoral, but not really equivalent to the way the US or UK systems work.

* Thanks to the commenters who have clarified it's not *strictly* required, it's also possible to have your body of work judged to be equivalent to having completed a Habilitation.

Comment: Many thanks @jovisg!!

Comment: To nitpick a bit here: The additional qualification for a professorship does not *need* to be a Habilitation. Doing enough work so that it counts as equivalent ("Habilitationsäquivalente Leistungen") is also sufficient. How common that route is depends on the subject culture. With the "1000 Tenure-Track Stellen Programm" by the federal government having started a while back, it's at least moderately common, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DCTLib!! From your comment I understand that the Habilitation and therefore the Habilitationsstelle is not really necessary (even though quite useful) to get a professorship (maybe directly as Associate Professor, W2)

Comment: @limone Yes, it's not strictly needed if the respective state laws mention the possibility of "Habilitationsäquivalente Leistungen" (which I believe all do). However, hiring committees will want to see substantial research experience, teaching experience, *and* success in attracting third party funding. Not all scientific positions enable you to work towards ticking all of these boxes.

Comment: thanks a lot @DCTLib!!